# logical and not checking both conditions

Tags: java, csv

I have this csv file which I'm reading using scanner:

```
pencil,XX,10
eraser,YY,rectangle
sharpener,YY,new
pencil,YY,12
```

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    item = scanner.next();
    property1 = scanner.next();
    property2 = scanner.next();
    if(!item.equals(args[1]) && !property1.equals(args[2])) {
       printWriter.println(item + "," + property1 + "," + property2);
    }
```

I want to write to file only when both conditions are true i.e. if my first argument is "pencil" and 2nd argument is "YY" then only the last line will be omitted but instead my current output is blank.

I did a sysout to check if my arguments and items/properties are matching and they do.

However if I remove one condition then it'll omit all lines having pencil as as "item" but I can't seem to understand why it's not writing only after checking both conditions. I'm new to java and kinda stuck here.

Comment: I might take a step back and break down what *exactly* your `if` expression actually evaluates to, like with a truth table. Include the non-negated values. This will be a valuable exercise.

Comment: Also, remember DeMorgan's Law: (not A and not B) = not (A or B), which can allow you to rewrite logical expressions in a more understandable form.

Comment: @ZephyrX can you rephrase your description? From the given input, what would be the expected output?

Comment: whoa! DeMorgan's law .I solved the issue now by removing negations and putting `continue;` in the block and writing to the file in the else statement. thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ZephyrX can you answer your own question to see what the solution was please?

Comment: @OscarRyz answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to basically delete a record from csv file whose name and property was given as a command line argument,

What I was doing wrong was putting two negative conditions with && and by DeMorgan's Law: (not A and not B) = not (A or B) (credits to @David R Tribble).

so the simple solution was:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
                item = scanner.next();
                property1 = scanner.next();
                property2 = scanner.next();
                if(item.equals(args[1]) && property1.equals(args[2])) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    printWriter.println(item + "," + property1 + "," + property2);
                }
            }
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is quite ambiguous. 
But one thing I'm sure of, `Java IF statement` with a logical and `&&` attempts to check the second condition only when the first condition is `true`. It directly goes to `else` block if it finds the first condition to be `false`

You can confirm this by running:

```
if (false && 1==(1/0)) {
    // if it checks for 1/0 it would fail with Math Exception.
} else {       
    System.out.println("Didn't check second condition as first was false);
}
```

Comment: It's not ambiguous at all, it's just incorrect. While what you're saying is correct, it's more of a comment than an answer, since it doesn't address their problem.